# Cordova Windows Universal App websockets not working

Tags: windows, cordova, mobile, universal

I'm working on a mobile application build with Cordova, my server is using WebSockets and is reachable in my App on iOS, but i want to use my client side app on Windows 10, so i did an Apache Cordova Windows Universal App. Problem is that the only way to make it work, is when i use the client on the same computer as the server. I have access to internet (internet capabilities already set up). Does anyone have an idea of what can block the access to external websockets ?

Answer (score 0):

If your backend web server will support SignalR you can use SignarR javascript plugin in your Apache Cordova project.

Thanks,
MG